# NFS/CIFS on Ubuntu

Tags: 13.04, nfs, cifs

Network File Server running on Ubuntu 13.04:

How to make Ubuntu 13.04 desktop my file server (NFS/CIFS shares) for Linux/Windiws clients using IPv4?

Answer (score 1):

The standard Linux daemon for setting up CIFS shares is called Samba. [The Ubuntu community help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide) shows you how to install it.

NFS shares can be set up following [these steps in the community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo).